# "'Request' object has no attribute 'learner'": Django Restframework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

There is an error in my code "'Request' object has no attribute 'learner'". Here, My requirement is "request.learner" is empty then  call "CDetailsSerializer" otherwise call "CourseDetailsSerializer".

```
 def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
            if not request.learner:
                serializer = CDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            else:
                serializer = CourseDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            print('s', serializer.data)
            response_data = {'course': serializer.data}
            return self.jp_response(s_code='HTTP_200_OK', data=response_data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return self.jp_error_response('HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR', 'EXCEPTION', [str(e), ])
```

Here always calling (else part) CourseDetailsSerializer, but in some situations, I also want to call (if part) CDetailsSerializer.Give me a solution to fix this.

Comment: It should be `request.POST['learner']` or `request.POST.get('learner')`

Comment: It's called `list`, so could well be `request.GET["learner"]`